# Populating two dropdown menus in one loop Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to populate two dropdown menus in Javascript with numbers within the same for loop, but only one is ever populated (the last one)

```
for (var i=1; i<10; i++)
{
   var option = document.createElement("option");
   option.text = i; 
   option.value = i;        
   document.getElementById('first').options.add(option);
   document.getElementById('second').options.add(option);               
}
```

The element 'second' will get populated, where as the other will not, if I put 'second' above 'first' then 'first' will be populated.

How can I do this without using two for loops? I have tried passing the ID via a function to the loop and I still get the same output.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Little modification in your script

```
for (var i=1; i<10; i++)
{
   var option = document.createElement("option");
   option.text = i;
   option.value = i;   
   var newOption = option.cloneNode(true);   

   document.getElementById('first').options.add(option);
   document.getElementById('second').options.add(newOption);               
}
```

Comment: I'm doing this in pure Javascript, i'm getting an error as .clone isn't actually a function?

Comment: @Elliott, my mistake I was using some library. Please refer update code with element.cloneNode(boolean) method